# Property 'Items' is 'ReadOnly' error VBA to VB.NET migration

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, migration

**Update2**

Please see my answer to my question.

**Update**

So, I updated the code per @Eddy comment below, however I'm still getting an error on the myRange = Globals.Sheet...line.

```
Dim xlDown, i As Int32
Dim myRange As Excel.Range

myRange = Globals.Sheet1.Application.Transpose(
                             Globals.Sheet1.Range(
                                 Globals.Sheet1.Range("A1"), 
                                 Globals.Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value)

 For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
      ListBox2.Items.Add(myRange.Cells(i, 1).Value)
 Next i
```

ERROR says:

> System.RuntimeType.ForwaredCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
>   BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
>   msgData) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.get_End(XlDirection
>   Direction)

Any Ideas?

Thanks again

---------------------------------Orig Question-------------------------------------

I have a VBA excel program that I'm converting to VB.net (using Visual Studio 2010) and I'm getting an error that I did not have in the old VBA version.  The error occurs when I try to transpose the excel range to a listbox:

> Property Items is readOnly

Within the With statment

```
Dim xlDown As Int32

With Globals.Sheet1
    ListBox2.Items = Globals.Sheet1.Application.Transpose(
                         Globals.Sheet1.Range(
                             Globals.Sheet1.Range("A1"), 
                             Globals.Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value)
End With
```

I'm not sure what to do with this, maybe I'm not referencing the Globals.Sheet1 correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a WITH statement, but then using the fully qualified name for the object? You more than likely need to use the .Add() method under .Items.

Comment: Right now, your `With` statement is useless... Your line should've looked like that : `ListBox2.Items = .Application.Transpose(.Range(...`. Also, if you don't have an object named `Globals` in your page or if you do but it doesn't have an object named `Sheet1` inside of it, then nothing can work.

Comment: Your text vs code puzzles me. Where are you comparing a cell value with items in a listbox? The only code I see tries to assign a range as the items for a listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further research I figured out that I did not have to use the transpose method to assign the excel.range values to a listbox.

Thank you to those who responded.

```
        Dim range As Excel.Range = Globals.Sheet1.UsedRange
        Dim obj As Object

        For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
            For cCnt = 1 To range.Columns.Count
                obj = CType(range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Excel.Range)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(obj.value)
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace the `Items` collection itself, you have to replace all items in it. You can use the `Clear` method to remove previous items, and the `AddRange` method to add new ones:

```
ListBox2.Items.Clear() ' If you need to remove previous items
ListBox2.Items.AddRange(Globals.Sheet1.Application.Transpose(Globals.Sheet1.Range(Globals.Sheet1.Range("A1"), Globals.Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value))
```

Comment: I made the update as you suggested, however now it says "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' accepts the number of arguments," error.

Comment: @artwork21: That's odd. All overloads accept only one argument: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t99s45wz.aspx

Comment: I don't know what this listbox exactly is (winforms listbox or an excel one) but doesn't the transpose return 1 Excel.Range object. How is that assignable as listbox items? Assuming it's a winform thing then the AddRange method here expects an IEnumerable<T> which a Excel.Range isn't

Comment: @Eddy, listbox is coming from a winform. So I cannot use Excel.Range then? It did work within Excel VBA which makes sense now.

Comment: Store the result from the transpose in a variable of type Excel.Range then loop through that (for i = 1 to myRange.Rows.Count) Listbox2.Add(myRange.Cells(i, 1).Value)

Comment: @artwork21: What is the exception type of the error? The part of the error message that you show only says that it occurs in a method in the `Range` class, not what the error is.

Comment: @Guffa ahh it says, "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT:0x800A03EC".

Comment: @artwork21: You are using the variable `xlDown` without assigning a value to it first.

Comment: @Guffa, thanks for your help, after doing some further research I figured out that I did not have to use the transpose method to assign the excel.range values to a listbox.  I posted my update as an answer, thx!!